# xlim does not change plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am new to matlab and I can't understand how to plot things.

I have images that are mostly empty space except for an important image in the center.  I want to use xlim and ylim to display only the important part of this image, but I can't seem to get anywhere:

```
I = imread("pout.tif");
figure(54)
sz=size(I);
disp(sz)
xv=1:sz(1);
yv=1:sz(2);
imagesc(xv,yv,I)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
xlim([50  100])
axis image;
```

For me this still generates the plot from x=0 to x=291, with the whole boy, not just his right arm from 50 to 100.

Comment: `axis image` is probably resetting the limits. Try swapping those two lines.

Comment: @Conotor Yep. From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#buk989s-1-style): _[...] It also sets `XLimMode`, `YLimMode`, and `ZLimMode` to `'auto'`_. By the way, [it`s a girl](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-import-and-export.html) :-)